# Add data from request POST into a table template [Django, Python]

Tags: python, html, django

I create a table show book info from SQLite database and I'm trying to create an "Add New Book form" to make it add a new book into a table database. How can I add a book and then make it show into the table Book Info ?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Add Book -->
    <div class="add-book">
        <h1>Add a Book</h1>
        <form action="/add_book" method="POST" class="add_more_book">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>
                <label for="title" id="title">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="input-title" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label id="desc" for="desc">Description:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="input-desc" rows="3"></textarea>
            </p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn shadow btn-primary" id="addbtn">
                Add
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Add Book -->

    <!-- Book info -->
    <div class="book-info">
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for i in all_books_info %}
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{i.id}}</th>
                        <td>{{i.title}}</td>
                        <td><a href="/books/{{i.id}}">Views</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have an a table named Bio in your models.py file. Like so

```
    class Bio(models.Model):
        author = models.CharField(max_length= 20, null=True)
        book = models.CharField(max_length= 20, null=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Assuming you have imported you models at the top of you views.py file.

```
   from .models import *
```

The * imports all the models from the models file.( There are reasons you may or may not want to import all the models in the future.)

In the views.py file

```
    def processInfo(request):
        print(request.POST["title"]
        if len(str(request.POST["title"])) < 2:
            print("Needs more the 2 characters to submit")
        else:
            print("Meets rule")
            Bio.objects.create(title = request.POST["title"])
```

The print is there to see if anything is received. You always want to check first if you are not getting an empty string. I use len and other tools to check https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp 
There are a few ways on creating and getting data from the django models. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Finally for the function that renders "/" in the views.py file. Once you retrieve the data that you are looking for, return it with the request and html file.